# Assigning classes within php / styling with css

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I'm trying to style a table i'm retrieving from my database. I'm currently echoing it out like this:

```
echo "<table class='rwd-table'>";

echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

      echo "<tr><td data-th='Movie Title'>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td data-th='Genre'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>
      <td data-th='Year'>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td><td data-th='Gross'" . $row['last_name'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";
```

And my css like this:

```
.rwd-table {
  ...
  tr {...
  }
  th {...
  }
  td {...
  }
}

.rwd-table {
  ...
}
```

But the css doesn't seem to affect anything. I'm acctually trying to apply this: 
https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg
To my situation. 
Please help.

Comment: you cant nest `CSS` unless you use something like `SAS`, so your `tr` cant be nested like that it has to be `.rwd-table tr{ ... }`  `.rwd-table td{ ... }` etc..  `SAS` is a parser library for the bootstrap library.  So that's a bit more then I care to get into   http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate what i put in the Comments, you can't nest CSS

```
.rwd-table {
  ...
  tr {...
  }
  th {...
  }
  td {...
  }
}

.rwd-table {
  ...
}
```

Like that, you have to do them on their own line like this

```
 .rwd-table tr{
  ...
 }

.rwd-table th{
  ...
 }

.rwd-table td{
  ...
 }
```

Or you can combine them if they have similar styles.

```
.rwd-table tr, .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td{
  ... similar styles ...
}

.rwd-table tr{
   ... additional unique styles ...
 }
```

Also of note is once the browser hits these CSS errors it stops processing the sheet, so nothing after it is applied either.  That's why none of your styles work.

It is possible to use this type of `nested` syntax but you have to use something like `SASS`

http://sass-lang.com/

Which is a CSS parser, kind of like a template engine, that takes the `SASS` style sheets and compiles it down to normal CSS, beforehand.

Personally I really wish that did work out of the box!

Comment: But if you check the link i provided they use nested css statements?

Comment: If you click on the gear ( at the top of the CSS box ) they are using SCSS, CSS per-processer.  It also says this next to the CSS (SCSS) title.  I've never used that one but I am sure it's similar to SASS.  In any case you should be able to just put them in your sheet the normal way as I outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to call the td through a class within your echo statement?

```
echo "<tr><td ***CLASS=“TEST”*** data-th='Movie Title'>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td data-th='Genre'>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td data-th='Year'>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td><td
```

You would then call the information from your CSS file through the TEST attribute.